# Half-Adder Digital Logic: Not as Expected

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit

In a lab for an "Introduction to Electric Circuits" course, I built a simple Half-Adder circuit using an [74LS08](http://www.futurlec.com/74LS/74LS08.shtml) IC & [74LS86](http://www.futurlec.com/74LS/74LS86.shtml) IC. However, I'm experiencing issues with the output.

My `input voltage` supplied to Pin 14 on the 74LS86 IC was **+5V** and I verified that the `output voltage` (Pin 3 on the 74LS86) was **+3.4V**. The results from this IC were what I had expected; however, the output of the `AND gate` (Pin 3 on the 74LS08) was **LOW** when the two inputs were **HIGH** and was **HIGH** when the inputs were **LOW**. Below is the `Truth Table` for the 74LSO8 IC.

```
A   B   Y
0   0   1
0   1   0
1   0   0
1   1   0
```

And here is the `Circuit Diagram`

[image]

What would cause this behavior? As I understand, when the inputs are LOW the output should be LOW and when the inputs are HIGH the output should be HIGH.

Comment: You've got the AND gate function wrong! Look it up.

Comment: @LeonHeller I did misunderstand the output when both inputs are LOW, but the functionality isn't as expected when the inputs are HIGH. For instance, when the inputs are HIGH the output is LOW and when the inputs are LOW the output is HIGH. What would explain this?

Comment: Can you make a photo of your actual circuit? We might see something in the construction that would explain what you're seeing.

Comment: I second ThePhoton's idea.

Comment: Adding real info regarding your particular circuit may help. As mentioned, photos with some labels would be useful in helping us help you.

Comment: And in addition to wiring problems: sometimes gates go bad.  Have you tried swapping out the 74LS08 for a different one (or at least using a different gate on the same chip?)

Comment: @Jay Greco I would love to provide you with a diagram of my circuit, but I can't upload images yet (as I have a low reputation).

Comment: @Wandering Logic I have tried another gate and I verified that the gates act the same. What I have found is that the 74LS08 acts more as a NOR gate rather than an AND gate.

Comment: Post a link to your image in a comment,  and someone with sufficient rep will add it to your post for you.

Comment: If you're getting only 3.4V on an output pin, you have something wrong. The outputs should always be within a few hundred millivolts of 0V or Vcc (5V in this case). I would field a guess that your AND gate is oscillating, probably because of a lack of bypass capacitors, or a floating input.

Comment: TTL specs anything more than about 2.2V as High (a logic '1') and anything less than 0.8 as a Low (logic '0'). Original 74xx were often seen outputting in the 2-3V region for highs. The 74LSxx were better, and 3.4V seems about typical. CMOS will get you closer to the 5V rail, e.g., the 74HCT stuff. But really there's nothing wrong with a '1' being 3.4V as long as everything meets the specs. And ironically, 4 decades down the road, everything moved to lower voltages anyway.

Comment: @Connor Wolf Here (http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/577/ng63.jpg/) is a link to the circuit that I am referring to. Could someone please edit this into my question above. Please post it under "And here is the `Circuit Diagram`"

Comment: @Jonathan I went ahead and edited it in to the post, but you actually have enough reputation now to do it yourself :)

Comment: @W5V0 Thanks for your help with that. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstood how AND gates work.  [Here](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/gatesfunc/) is a very nice list of truth tables for various digital logic circuits.  AND gates are only high when both inputs are high.  You are thinking of an XNOR gate which produces a high output whenever both inputs are the same.  The AND truth table is:

```
1in 2in out
0   0   0
0   1   0
1   0   0
1   1   1
```

and the xor is:

```
1in 2in out
0   0   0
0   1   1
1   0   1
1   1   0
```

Another thing you can do is check to make sure the AND gate is working as it should.  Disconnect the XOR gate and connect the two inputs directly to the AND inputs and make sure the outputs match the truth table.

Comment: I had forgotten my simple AND logic for the case in which the inputs are LOW, but the output is LOW when the inputs are HIGH. What would cause this?

Comment: Are you completely sure you have the circuit properly connected?  Also, are you completely sure of the parts you are using?  If the output is as you say, it sounds like you may be using a NAND gate instead of an AND gate.  What are the outputs of the AND gate when the inputs are different?  If the output is high when the inputs are different, you have a NAND gate.

Comment: It functions properly for all cases except when the inputs are HIGH. When the inputs are HIGH, the output is LOW.

Comment: @JonathanWhitaker Check my edited answer.

Comment: I have edited my original post, take a look at the `Truth Table` for the outputs that I am receiving. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Hmm, that is very strange, have you tried using a different 74LSO8 IC?

Comment: Indeed I have. It's almost as if Fairchild Semiconductor produced the wrong chip :).

Comment: The only other possible idea I have is that are you sure your DC supply polarities and switches are correct?  Reverse polarities/switch would still produce the same xor output, but it seems your AND gate is reverse of what it should be, ie. your 0's are 1's and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the AND gate. It is high only when both inputs are high. Not also when they are both low, as you said. And if one is high and one is low, the output is also low.

Comment: Ok, so aside from being HIGH when the inputs are LOW I should expect to see that the output is HIGH when both inputs are HIGH. That being said, the main issue is that when the inputs are both HIGH the output is LOW. Likewise, when the inputs are LOW, the output is HIGH.